# How can I see all the albums that have been shared with me in Picasa Web Albums?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I can't find the page where I could see all the albums other users have given me access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information used to be buried away under favorites, and could be accessed as follows

> http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/favorites for what appears to be a full
>   list.

Unfortunately, with the blurring of the line between picasaweb and google+, this information is no longer obviously available.

Comment: How can I get to `favorites` from home page of Picasa web Albums @itj

Comment: I see. Just open the link

Comment: I cannot see the shared album here @itj All I see now is the `People I'm Following`